# Method not firing on textbox text change

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox with a calander extender attached:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="customDateTo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectionChanged="customDateFrom_SelectionChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="toCalendarExtender" TargetControlID="customDateTo" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

As you see I have `AutoPostBack="true"` and `OnSelectionChanged="customDateFrom_SelectionChanged` assigned for the textbox.

However nothing is responding in my method:

```
protected void customDateFrom_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Do Something");
}
```

When I change the text I do get a postback but nothing within the method is executing. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: text change is another event `TextBox.TextChanged Event` and you are showing about selection change..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a **[TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox_methods.aspx)**, I think it should be;

```
OnTextChanged="customDateFrom_SelectionChanged"
```

Not

```
OnSelectionChanged="customDateFrom_SelectionChanged"
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to handle the `TextBox`' `TextChanged` event instead. `SelectionChanged` is a winforms event which doesn't exist in ASP.NET.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="customDateTo" runat="server" 
   AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="customDateFrom_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox>
```

This event is raised when the user changes the text in it and leaves the `TextBox`.

```
protected void customDateFrom_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Do Something");
}
```

Another reason for not triggering an event is if you databind the `TextBox` before the event is triggered (f.e. in `Page_Load`). Then you should check `IsPostBack`: `if(!IsPostBack)DataBindTextBox();`.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the [TextBox.TextChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx)..

example:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged">
```

// server side event:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text);
}
```

Refer:
[Asp.Net textbox TextChanged event is not firing](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/436223/Asp-Net-textbox-TextChanged-event-is-not-firing)